# Testing promise existence in Record<string, Promise> raises typescript error

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript-typings

I don't understand why typescript raise the following error when I test the existence of a promise in an object.

> This condition will always return true since this 'Promise' is
> always defined.
>
> Did you forget to use 'await'?

Do I need to change something with my types ?

```typescript
const xRecord: Record<string, Promise<number>> = {}
const generateX = async () => {
  // long async stuff here
  return Math.random()
}

const getX = async (key: string) => {
  if(xRecord[key]){ // typescript error here
    return xRecord[key]
  }
  return xRecord[key] = generateX()
}
const x = await getX('foo')
const x2 = await getX('foo')
```

Comment: The warning message says it as it is. Your `if` is testing the truthiness of a promise object. An object is *always* truthy.

Comment: You may set the compiler option  `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` to `true` or explicitly set the values of the record as `Promise<number> | undefined`; or use an explicit method to test the existence of the key (as opposed to the current truthy test)

Answer (score 1):

The warning is appropriate, as indeed a (promise) object is always truthy. If however the aim is to test whether the `xRecord` *has* the `key`, then do:

```
if (key in xRecord)
```

As this will also look in the object prototype chain, you *may* want to be more specific that you are looking for an **own** property:

```
if (Object.hasOwn(xRecord, key))
```

Comment: This is strange. Why is this the case only for promises? I've tried the same thing with enums, obejcts, HTMLElements, and other random types that I assume can only be truthy, and the error does not occur.

Comment: The error message is specific for promises since it highlights a common mistake where coders think they are testing the *value* to which a promise *resolved*, but are instead testing the promise object itself. Note that the message speaks of `await`... which is promise related.

Comment: This does make the message misleading, then. It's not that it's actually guaranteed to be true here, just that the developer has likely potentially misused their dictionary of promises.